# Geodesic invariant under isometry is a reparametrization?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, smooth-manifolds

Suppose we have a geodesic $\gamma: I \to M$ in a Riemannian manifold $M$, $I \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ some interval, and an Riemannian isometry $\phi$ with $\phi(\gamma(I)) = \gamma(I)$. Is it true that there exists some smooth $\varphi$ with $\phi \circ \gamma = \gamma \circ \varphi$?

If it is true then $\varphi$ is forced to be $\varphi(t) = \pm t + b$, because of the geodesic differential equation and the fact that $||\frac{d}{dt}(\gamma \circ \varphi)|| = ||\frac{d}{dt}(\phi \circ \gamma)||$, since $\phi$ is a isometry and therefore $\phi \circ \gamma$ a geodesic.

It seems true for me, because some function $\varphi: I \to I$ with $\phi \circ \gamma = \gamma \circ \varphi$ must exist, since by assumption $\phi(\gamma(I)) = \gamma(I)$. So, we only would need to invert $\gamma$ on a little piece, which is possible, because w.l.o.g. $\gamma$ is an immersion, i.e. $\gamma: J \to \gamma(J)$ is a diffeomorphism ($J \subseteq I$ open interval, $\gamma(J) \subseteq M$ embedded submanifold). But why should it be guaranteed that $\phi \circ \gamma(J') \subseteq \gamma(J)$ for some open interval $J \subset I$?

Does anybody know if and why it is true? Is my idea correct?

Or, if it is false: do you know some counterexamples, and maybe some further assumption such that it is actually true?

Comment: No. Think about reflecting (e.g., in a sphere) across the midpoint of $\gamma(I)$. In general, we don't allow reparametrizations to change the orientation.

Comment: You want to mean that the reparametrization $\varphi$ needs to be increasing?

Comment: A priori all smooth $\varphi$'s are allowed.